# MQTTJS - Pull versionNum/username/password from client object

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mqtt

Am I doing something wrong with the server for https://github.com/adamvr/MQTT.js? I see `client.id` come in fine. Everything else comes in as undefined; I verified the MQTT client's info with another broker using 3.1 user/pass, so I know the issue is not there.

```
    clients = { }

    server = mqtt.createServer (client) =>
      console.log 'Broker:mqtt:createServer'

      # Catch when client connects
      client.on 'connect', (packet) =>
        console.log 'Broker:connect'

        client.connack
          returnCode: 0

        client.id = packet.client

        console.log 'version: ' + client.versionNum # undefined
        console.log 'client: ' + client.id # COMES THROUGH FINE!
        console.log 'username: ' + client.username # undefined
        console.log 'password: ' + client.password # udefined

        clients[client.id] = client

        console.log 'clients: ' + JSON.stringify clients

   ...

    server.listen 1883
```

I also created an issue under the project: https://github.com/adamvr/MQTT.js/issues/22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client object you receive on the `connect` event doesn't contain any of the parameters you're seeking. The only reason `client.id` has the correct value is because you're setting it in the line above. The `packet` passed with the event contains the properties.

```
clients = { }

server = mqtt.createServer (client) =>
  console.log 'Broker:mqtt:createServer'

  # Catch when client connects
  client.on 'connect', (packet) =>
    console.log 'Broker:connect'

    client.connack
      returnCode: 0

    client.id = packet.client

    console.log 'version: ' + packet.versionNum
    console.log 'client: ' + packet.client
    console.log 'username: ' + packet.username
    console.log 'password: ' + packet.password

    clients[client.id] = client

    console.log 'clients: ' + JSON.stringify clients

 ...

server.listen 1883
```

Comment: What's interesting is that the versionNum that comes through is always 3, but the username/password do come through perfectly!  Thanks.